# Dividing Array in half

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, for-loop, data-conversion

I am having trouble with my trial-and-error code. It's hard coded for what I am needing it to do... where the array is set to get random binary when it's ran. I wanted to isolate the problem, but it never wants to print numerator and denominator's values! So my assumption is it's never getting the said values.

I hard-coded something because I wanted to see if this would work, dividing an array of 0's and 1's. I converted the first half (of 8 bits) to a string, then parsed it to numerator. I did the same for the second set of 8-bits, and parsed it to the denominator. However, it's not working and I am stumped. The array is supposed to hold 16 values (elements : 0-15).

```
package runTests;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class runTestGetBinaryStrands {
    protected static int getBits[] = {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0};
    double numerator, denominator, x, y;

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        runTestGetBinaryStrands test = new runTestGetBinaryStrands();
        test.getNumber(null, getBits);
    }

    public void getNumber(String convert, int[] tempBinary) {
        /*Should get 16 integers at most in the array at a time & divide
        * by 2 to seperate/parse the values.*/

        //getBits = new int [16];

        for (int i = 0; i > getBits.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < getBits.length; j++) {//start at index 0 to 7 = 8.
                tempBinary = Arrays.copyOfRange(getBits, 0, 7); //Get first set of 8 elements.
                convert = tempBinary.toString();
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(convert); //converts string to one whole section in
                System.out.println("See Numerator's value: " + numerator);

                tempBinary= Arrays.copyOfRange(getBits, 8, 15); //Get Second set of 8 elements.
                convert = tempBinary.toString();
                denominator = Integer.parseInt(convert); //converts string to one whole section in.
                System.out.println("See Denominator's value: " + denominator);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice on why this isn't working? Cheers! TG52.

Comment: Probably need to change i > getBits.length to i < getBits.length to start

Comment: Uh.... silly me! Thank you!! Just have to fix a bug... NumberFormatException.java:65... and I am golden. I ALWAYS flip those things. THANK YOU!!! ^.^