# Conversion from parsing a String to double is returning 0.0:

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, type-conversion, double

This is a follow up on the last question I made regarding this topic. It's a different issue though.

My code is working, except it's copying some sort of address using the copyOfRange. It always returns 0.0 due to an address of some sort, instead of the section of the array getBits.

Can someone please scan this is and make a suggestion? I am going crazy over this (it's not an assignment).

```
package runTests;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class runTestGetBinaryStrands {
    protected static int getBits[] = {1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0};
    double numerator, denominator, x, y;

    public static void main (String[] args){
        runTestGetBinaryStrands test = new runTestGetBinaryStrands();
        test.getNumber(null, getBits);
    }
    /*NOTE OF THIS FORLOOP:     * Divided the bits array in half & convert two different binary values to a string  * I parsed the string to an int value, which can be put saved to a double and be treated like a decimal value.  * I got the first 8 elements and stashed them into numerator, and did the same for denominator for the remaining array bits.    * * The chromosome has one binary string, made up of a bunch of smaller parts.* You use getNumber in the chromosome to get out the values of the parts.     **/     

    public void getNumber(String convert, int[] tempBinary){       
        for (int i = 0; i < getBits.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < getBits.length; j++){ //start at index 0 to 7 = 8.
                tempBinary = Arrays.copyOfRange(getBits, 0, 7); //Get first set of 8 elements.
                convert = tempBinary.toString();
                System.out.println(convert);
                try{
                    numerator = Integer.parseInt(convert); //converts string to one whole section in
                }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                }
                System.out.println("See Numerator's value: " + numerator);                          
                tempBinary= Arrays.copyOfRange(getBits, 8, 15); //Get Second set of 8 elements.
                convert = tempBinary.toString();
                try{
                    denominator = Integer.parseInt(convert); //converts string to one whole section in
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                }                           
                System.out.println("See Denominator's value: " + denominator);
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Reference for previous topic: this is not a duplicate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29334506/dividing-array-in-half?noredirect=1#comment46857736_29334506

Comment: The third argument in `Arrays.copyOfRange()` is exclusive.  So you want to change the 7 to and 8 and the 15 to a 16.  Also, what are you expecting `convert = tempBinary.toString()` to do?  Do you want a String of 1's and 0's, like "10110100"?  Because that's not what's happening.

Comment: Quicksilver002, that's exactly what I was wanting. I thought the array was 0-based?

Comment: I was hoping that `convert = tempBinary.toString()` (my string: convert) would be assigned the values of tempBinary. From there, I was hoping to rip the binary values from it into one number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the lines `convert = tempBinary.toString();` with:

```
    convert = "";
    for(int bin : tempBinary){
      convert += bin;
    }
```

That should get your conversion working.